# How to do a if statement and loop in cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos, cmd

I want to check if a file exists in a path and then if it exists do a loop. e.g.

```
IF EXIST "C:\FILE" THEN
LOOP CONDITION
END IF
```

but in .cmd programming. How would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like this:

```
IF EXIST filename. (
FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) DO GOTO=%%A
    :1
    ECHO 1
    GOTO End
    :2
    ECHO 2
    GOTO End
    :3
    ECHO 3
    :End
) ELSE (
echo filename. missing.
)
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php)

Comment: Thank you. I do have a further question, where it says 'filename.' do i add the path in quotes? e.g. IF EXISTS "C:\FILENAME".(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Visual Basic (at least the syntax of IF statement
is showing it), if yes, then use FileInfo object like
Dim fi As New FileInfo("C:\File.txt")
IF fi.Exists() THEN
' Do your loop here
END IF